# mainWindow.loadURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, electron

I am getting this error but not getting the solution to resolve this issue.

> mainWindow.loadURL is not a function

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {Menu} = require('electron');
const {app} = require('electron');
const BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
const conn = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
var mainWindow;
app.on('ready', function () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1024, height: 768, backgroundcolor: 'black' });
    **mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({** //Here I am getting an error.
        pathname: 'popupcheck.html',
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.setProgressBar(1);
});
```

Comment: what version of electron are you using ?

Comment: make sure you are using the last version of electron, i had the same problem and it solved

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi I had to go back to an earlier version of electron for electron-rebuild to work, and now this breaks?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the `BrowserWindow` module like this:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
```

[BrowserWindow docs](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#browserwindow)